# Can we use loop in jspdf autotable in angular

Tags: angular

I have a jspdf code that is already working but i want to change it and use a loop to print array data and i'm not sure how to implement in a correct way.Below ill share my jspdf code

```
downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {  
    debugger      
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let rows: Array<any> = [];
    let medicineInfo: any;
    let physicianInfo: any;
    doc.page = 1;

     var col = ["Test Name", "Result", "Unit" , "Reference"];
this.hubxDataItemSpList.forEach((a) => {
  medicineInfo = this.hubxDataItemSpList.find(x => x.id == a.id);
  rows.push(['' + a.itemTitle + '', '' + a.itemValue + '', '' + a.itemUnit ]);
});
    
    
    if (this.prescriptionModel.id > 0) {                 
        if (this.reportCommonData != null) {
          doc.setProperties({title: "Prescription Report"});  
          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.setFontSize(16);
          doc.text(15, 20, "Prescription Report");
          doc.setFontSize(10);
          
          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.text(140, 20, "Provider Details:");
          doc.setFont("normal");
          doc.text(140, 25, "Name: " + this.reportCommonData.organizationName);
          doc.text(140, 30, "Address: " + this.reportCommonData.address);
          doc.text(140, 35, "Phone: " + this.reportCommonData.phone);
          doc.text(140, 40, "Email: " + this.reportCommonData.email);
          
          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.text(15, 35, "Patient Details:");
          doc.setFont("normal");
          doc.text(15, 40, "Name: " + this.reportCommonData.firstName + " " + this.reportCommonData.lastName);
          doc.text(15, 45, "MRN: " + this.reportCommonData.patientMRN);
          doc.text(15, 50, "Email: " + this.reportCommonData.patientEmail);
          doc.text(15, 55, "Phone: " + this.reportCommonData.patientPhone);          
          
          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.text(140, 50, "Physician Details:");
          doc.setFont("normal");
          doc.text(140, 55, "Name: " + physicianInfo.firstName + " " + physicianInfo.lastName);
          doc.text(140, 60, "NPI Number: " + physicianInfo.npiNumber);
          doc.text(140, 65, "Phone: " + physicianInfo.phoneNumber);
          
          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.text(15, 65, 'Pharmacy Details:');
          doc.setFont("normal");
          doc.text(15, 70, "Name: " + this.PharmacyInfo.pharmacyName);
          doc.text(15, 75, "Address: " + this.PharmacyInfo.address1);
          doc.text(15, 80, "City: " + this.PharmacyInfo.city);
          doc.text(15, 85, "Email: " + this.PharmacyInfo.email);
          doc.text(15, 90, "Phone:" + this.PharmacyInfo.phone);
          doc.text(15, 95, "Prescription Date: " + this.datePipe.transform(this.prescriptionModel.createdDate, 'M/d/yyyy, h:mm a'));

          doc.autoTable({
            columnStyles: {
              0: { cellWidth: 120 },
              1: { cellWidth: 40 },
              2: { cellWidth: 20 }
            },
            head: [col],
            body: rows,
            startY: 100,
            theme: 'plain',
            tableLineColor: [242, 238, 238],
            tableLineWidth: 0.5,
            styles: {
              font: 'courier',
              lineColor: [242, 238, 238],
              lineWidth: 0.5
            },
          });

          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.setFontSize(7);
          doc.text(15,260, "xyz");
          doc.setFont("normal");          
          doc.text(15,265, "xyz");
          doc.text(15,270, "xyz ");
          doc.text(15,275, "xyz.");
          
          doc.setFont("bold");
          doc.text(65,280,"xyz");

          doc.setFontSize(5);          
          doc.setFont("normal");
          doc.text(180, 285,'Powered by xyz');

          if(!isSubmit){     
            window.open(doc.output('bloburl'))
          }else{                        
            this.fileList.push({
              data: doc.output('datauristring'), 
              ext: 'pdf'            
            });
          }
       }      
    }
  }
```

and below this code ill share a code that i want to pull this logic to the above code. i want to loop the autptable as the same ways im looping at the below code.

```
<div *ngFor="let hubxReport of hubxReportList; let i=index">
   <div>{{hubxReport.categoryName}}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
        <div>{{item.itemTitle}} {{item.itemValue}} {{item.itemUnit}}
   </div>
</div>
```

i want to loop the above jspdf code the same way im looping in this html code.is it possible to implement. I'm new to angular.thanks

and the loop that i tried

```
let col1 = [];
    let rows = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.hubxDataItemSpList[0].categoryName.length; i++)
    {
      
        col1.push(this.hubxDataItemSpList[0].categoryName)
        i++;
      
     
      for(let j = 0; j < this.hubxDataItemSpList.length; j++)
      {
       rows.push(this.hubxDataItemSpList[0].itemTitle,this.hubxDataItemSpList[0].itemValue,this.hubxDataItemSpList[0].itemUnit)
      }
    }
```